# Ruby Dynamic Array: undefined local variable or method `s' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby, arrays, dynamic

I'm still new at ruby.
My array is not being seen for some reason.
I tested my code logic in irb, and it seemed to work alright, but when I have it in if statements, it breaks with the error in the title.

```
$s = []

i = 0

File.open("test.log").each do | l |
    if l =~ /(m.)/
        s << [$1]
        i=i+1
    end

    if l =~ /(p.)/
        s[i-1] << $1
    end

end

s.each do |g|
    p g
end
```

An example test.log:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
m1
ggg
p1
p2
p3
p4
oooooooooooooo
m2
p1
p2
p3
p4
p5
gggggggggggggg
m3
p1
kkkkkkkkkkkk
m4
m5
llllllllllllll
```

How can I end up with an array s, like such?

```
[[m1,p1,p2,p3,p4], [m2,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5], [m3,p1], [m4], [m5]]
```

Comment: +0 for not bothering to check that the code you posted gives the same error message as you stated in the question.

Comment: fixed. Didn't think it was such big deal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've declared the array as `$s`, but are trying to access it as `s`. These are two different variables as far as Ruby is concerned. You should either declare it as `s = []` or access it always as `$s`, e.g. `$s << [$1]`.

EDIT: Because the comment is so popular, I'll add that [Ruby global variables](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope#Ruby_Global_Variables) (i.e. those that begin with `$`) can lead to very-difficult-to-debug situations, and I would discourage you from using them. I'm not able to think of a situation of using a global where a cleaner solution isn't possible.

Comment: Should also be noted that using global variables (those that begin with `$`) is frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks! good catch, didn't know it :)
*pulls some hairs off* I realized my main mistake was on the regex. The original code had more complex regex, and I missed it.

Comment: Without seeing a stack trace, I'm not going to worry about the actual error.

Comment: Its actually `s' not `_'. I put it there so it wouldn't be specific to this problem

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize a new sub-array in your main array each time you hit an `m` line.  If you hit a `p` line, you append to that same index.

```
index = -1;
array = []
File.open("test.log").each do |line|
  if line =~ /m./
    index = index + 1
    array[index] = []
    array[index] << line
  end

  if line =~ /p./
    array[index] << line
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Ron. I got the answer above though.